# I can not see my checkbox android

Tags: android, layout

why I can not see my chechbox ?

this is my screenshot of my layout :

[image]

I think it is due to my custom background !
Even if I change/remove the background does not affect!

why?!!!!!!!

How can I solve it?

layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <CheckBox 
     android:id="@+id/checkbox_amir_ghamsari"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
     android:background="#ffffff"
     />
 <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/textview_amir_ghamsari"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/checkbox_amir_ghamsari"
     android:layout_alignTop="@id/checkbox_amir_ghamsari"
     android:text="@string/textview_amir_ghamsari"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:textSize="@dimen/amir_masoud_size"
     android:textColor="#ffffff"
     android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
     />
 <CheckBox 
     android:id="@+id/checkbox_s_masoud_emamian"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@id/checkbox_amir_ghamsari"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
     android:background="#46462e"
     />
 <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/textview_s_masoud_emamian"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/checkbox_s_masoud_emamian"
     android:layout_alignTop="@id/checkbox_s_masoud_emamian"
     android:text="@string/textview_s_masoud_emamian"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:textSize="@dimen/amir_masoud_size"
     android:textColor="#ffffff"
     android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
     />
 <EditText 
     android:id="@+id/edittext_sms"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="@string/edittext_hint_comments"
     android:lines="5"
     android:background="#46462e"
     android:textColor="#ffffff"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     />
 <ImageButton 
     android:id="@+id/imagebutton_send_sms"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:src="@drawable/send_sms"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I added it, but I dont see any checkbox !

Comment: what color you are using in the background of your parent layout?

Comment: Well, do you really need to add a TextView next to your CheckBox? a CheckBox can have its own text...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this layout...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_amir_ghamsari"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="amir_ghamsari" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_amir_ghamsari"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textview_amir_ghamsari"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textview_amir_ghamsari"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview_amir_ghamsari" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_s_masoud_emamian"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textview_amir_ghamsari"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkbox_amir_ghamsari"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="masoud_emamian" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_s_masoud_emamian"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textview_s_masoud_emamian"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textview_s_masoud_emamian"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkbox_amir_ghamsari" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkbox_s_masoud_emamian"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:background="#46462e"
        android:hint="hint_comments"
        android:lines="5"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ImageButton

        android:id="@+id/imagebutton_send_sms"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/send_sms"
 />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set drawable and check if its working or not.
[Check this link](http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.sg/2012/12/how-to-use-and-custom-checkbox-in.html)

Please check this blog.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/check" />
<item android:state_checked="false"
android:drawable="@drawable/uncheck" />
</selector>

 <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="CheckBox 1"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
       android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector" />
```